# Facebook iframe embed in profile pages - what the heck

Tags: facebook, embed

We're looking for a way to embed an iframe and specific content into a fan page (not a profile). Apparently it's not directly allowed using the fb:iframe tag but I did find some hints here: http://www.facebook.com/PagesDesign#/profile.php?fbhref=iportfolio.html%3F_fb_fromhash%3D53f3ede8dd88aad33d3bc346401a683c&id=92993272816&app_page=1&v=app_96944267235

Looking for a more direct way though.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a good way to do that: iframes are specifically blocked in fan pages.  If you've got an iframe application and you want to have a tab show up, you can force it to work as FBML by appending fb_force_mode to the query string.

Comment: But if it's not possible then how did that company manage to do it? The sample you provided seems to talk about Applications specifically. Hmmmmmm.

Comment: Based on a quick look at that page, I'd guess it's not an iframe application but just a standard FBML one.

Pages can add FB applications (with some limitations), but they need to be of the FBML variety and not iframe.  You can also drop static HTML/FBML into applications easily.  In both cases, you can embed FBML, Facebook widgets, and Flash.

Comment: Yeah that's what I assumed but the data on many of those pages seems to be dynamic. Could it be that the developers have coded the entire thing in FBML then used FBJS and FB data proxy services to deliver the data dynamically? That's the ONLY way I could think that it could be done with dynamic data.

Comment: You can make a page in FBML that uses the API (PHP or your flavor of choice) to make dynamic calls, provided the fan page adds that application as a tab (a little weird of a process, but it works).  Your suggestion of FBJS to do ajax-y calls would work as well.